# How do we implement nested while loop in PHP?

Tags: php

Can someone help me on how to implement a nested while loop in PHP?

Please give some example it will be highly appreciated. I am getting problem in internal while:

```
while ($record = db_fetch_object($username)) 
{ 
   $userArray[] = $record->uid;   //print "waheed----";

   while($recordfile = db_fetch_Object($userfile))
   {
    print "waheed";
    $userArray [$record->uid][] = $recordfile->fid;        
   }  
}
```

Comment: `while ($something) { while ($anotherthing) { do_stuff(); } }` - this doesn't work? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried so far?

Comment: question is unclear, can you specify what exactly do you need?

Comment: Unreadable code doesn't make anything clearer. Update your question instead and use code formattings.

Comment: dude put you recent code in your question by editing your question

Answer (score 5):

```
while($condition1)
{
    while($condition2)
    {
        // statements
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I guess this is the problem with the while loop of AAMIR:

$recordfile = db_fetch_Object($userfile)

the word object has Capital case 'O'. Make it small.